# Does TCP scale to fast networks?

Tags: tcp

It seems the maximum TCP receive window size is 1GB (when scaling is used). So then the largest RTT that would still make it possible to fill a 100Gb pipe with one connection is 40ms (because 2 * 40E-3 * 100E9 / 8 = 1GB). That would limit that sort of communication speed to a distance IRO 10000 kilometres.

Another scaling problem seems to be that 32-bit sequence numbers don't offer protection against duplicated packets delayed by more than about 400ms (because they wrap around in that amount of time). They also limit the window size to 2GB (because they need to be split between the sender and receiver window).

Three questions:

I am aware of TCP timestamps that can help solve the problem of sequence numbers, but I would like to know if that is a feature that just happens to help but was really designed for some other purpose. Also, I don't understand what it is that timestamps achieve that could not be done simply by increasing the number of bits used for sequence numbers.

I don't understand why the maximum receive window is just 1GB as opposed to 2GB that would presumably be trivially possible with the current headers.

Finally, I would like to know if TCP already scales well enough to be used over the sort of links that are supposedly coming soon.

Many thanks.

Comment: This just *might* be on topic here, not sure. If you don't get an answer or it's closed as off-topic here, you may consider [networkengineering.SE].

Comment: +1 But the reason I'm going to say it doesn't matter is because you're talking about *one TCP connection*. I'm not sure that you could expect any single application to saturate a 10Gb+ pipe. I could certainly be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP features you're talking about were specified in [RFC 1323](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1323) in the early 1990s. The limitations you're encountering are justified by discussion text in the RFC:

- The sequence number appears in the middle of the [TCP segment header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) and could not have been lengthened without an incompatible change.
- Using timestamps allows for the protocol to simultaneously measure round-trip time and protect against wrapped sequence numbers. Making the sequence number bigger would not provide any information about round-trip time.
- You need the timestamps in order to measure round-trip time accurately. Measuring round-trip time without timestamps is a sampling problem, and the sampling becomes unsolvable due to aliasing if you get more than 1 error per window.
- A 1 GB receive window is the largest that can be kept in sync across the connection. The RFC explains it about as well as can be done:

> ```
> TCP determines if a data segment is "old" or "new" by testing
> whether its sequence number is within 2**31 bytes of the left edge
> of the window, and if it is not, discarding the data as "old".  To
> insure that new data is never mistakenly considered old and vice-
> versa, the left edge of the sender's window has to be at most
> 2**31 away from the right edge of the receiver's window.
> Similarly with the sender's right edge and receiver's left edge.
> Since the right and left edges of either the sender's or
> receiver's window differ by the window size, and since the sender
> and receiver windows can be out of phase by at most the window
> size, the above constraints imply that 2 * the max window size
> must be less than 2**31, or
>
>    max window < 2**30
> ```

As [Jonathon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119527/jonathon-reinhart) mentioned earlier, these limitations are per-TCP connection. It's tough to think of a scenario where a single application could reach the limits of a single TCP connection, and tougher to think of one where the application couldn't open additional connection(s) if needed.

Comment: Many thanks. I don't understand why the RTT measurement needs that level of support. It's not like it's difficult to start a timer when sending a packet and stop it on receiving an ack, and TCP is doing that already? Also, I still don't understand where the 2^31 limit comes from (I don't doubt the need for using just a half of it). Obviously, using all 2^32 seq numbers gives less protection against duplicated delayed packets, but it's not like using a half is a fundamental improvement? I am sure we will find examples where scaling matters as soon as the technology is available:-) Thanks again.

Comment: There's more detail on why you need timestamps for RTT on p. 11-12 of RFC 1323, which is basically a mini-networking textbook, and which I wish I'd read in that class :). The ACK-sampling approach you describe was tried in the late '80s and found to produce useless estimates on unreliable networks.

Comment: I've edited the answer to pull in that information from the RFC.

Comment: WA: Thanks. My response was already based on the whole excerpt. What I am getting at is that detection of old packets is already unreliable when the window size gets to 2^30. I am failing to see how it gets *fundamentally* worse with a window size of 2^31. So I don't see how it helps to arbitrarily restrict the size to 2^30. I do see that the send/receive window sizes together cannot add up to more than 2^32. But it seems to me that if timestamps are used then there is no reason not to have windows 2^31 large? Many thanks for referencing page 11 of the RFC, I'll read the whole thing.

Comment: It doesn't get worse; the issue is that, like extending the sequence number, it would require changing the definition of TCP incompatibly, and then negotiating a TCP version on each connection. This has caused [a great deal of pain](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/27/tlssymmetriccrypto.html) in TLS.

The authors of RFC 1323 worked _very_ hard to make sure that none of the extensions they implemented would cause an older implementation to misunderstand packets sent by a newer one.